# Attempt to add a select command to datatool running into Runaway error

Tags: macros, datatool

In connection with a side project, I would like to add a SQL-like select and where to the `datatool` package.  The `\DTselect` command would allow me to specify a list of columns and an existing table name and have a new table of only the selected columns placed in an output table.  Eventually, I would like to add a `\DTwhere` that would allow me to select a set of rows and output to a new named table.  But I am stuck on the `\DTselect` issue and am hoping to get some help from one or more LaTeX wizards.

The following example shows how I plan to set up tables, using a toy 'seq' table of letter names in various languages.  It would allow the user to add a row to the table with `\addSeq`, giving the field values in a xkeyval optional argument and an 'id' in the single mandatory argument.

Here is my MWE, or rather, Mnon-WE.  I get a runaway argument error and I am at a loss as to why.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter

% Check whether db named in #1 exists.  If not, issue error message in #2.
\newcommand{\checkfordb}[2]{\DTLifdbempty{#1}{\errmessage{#2}}{\relax}}

% Add fields #2 to a database #1
% #1->dbname, #2-><field name list>
\newcommand{\addcolstodb}[2]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\DTLaddcolumn{#1}{##1}}%
  \dolistloop{#2}}

% Add #4 to table #1 if #3 is in list of fields #2. Used in \DTselect below.
% #1->dbname, #2-><fieldname>, #3-><select fields>, #4->item
\newcommand{\addtodbfield}[4]{%
  \xifinlist{#2}{#3}%
  {\DTLnewdbentry{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
  {}}

\DTLnewdb{seqs}
\DTLaddcolumn{seqs}{id}
\DTLaddcolumn{seqs}{roman}
\DTLaddcolumn{seqs}{greek}
\DTLaddcolumn{seqs}{hebrew}

\define@key{addSeq}{roman}{\DTLnewdbentry{seqs}{roman}{#1}}
\define@key{addSeq}{greek}{\DTLnewdbentry{seqs}{greek}{#1}}
\define@key{addSeq}{hebrew}{\DTLnewdbentry{seqs}{hebrew}{#1}}

\newcommand{\addSeq}[2][]{%
  \DTLnewrow{seqs}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{seqs}{id}{#2} %
  \setkeys{addSeq}{#1}}

\newcommand{\makeTable}[2][]{%
    \DTLdisplaylongdb[caption={Simple table #2},#1]{#2}}

% Here is where the trouble is:
\newcommand*{\DTselect}[3]{%
  \checkfordb{#1}{Table named #1 does not exist.}%
  \forcsvlist{\listadd\LDcols}{#2}%
  \DTLnewdb{#3}%
  \addcolstodb{#3}{\LDcols}
  \DTLforeach*{#1}{}{%
    \DTLforeachkeyinrow{\LDvalue}{%
      \addtodbfield{#3}{\dtlkey}{\LDcols}{\LDvalue}}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Set up a table
\addSeq[roman=A, greek=alpha, hebrew=aleph]{aaa}
\addSeq[roman=B, greek=beta, hebrew=beth]{bbb}
\addSeq[roman=D, greek=delta, hebrew=dalet]{ddd}
\addSeq[roman=G, greek=gamma, hebrew=gimel]{ggg}

% Print it
\makeTable{seqs}

\DTselect{seqs}{greek, hebrew}{foreign}
\makeTable{foreign}

\end{document}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
\q@nil \edef \dtl@dogetentry {\noexpand \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow {\noexpand \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@dtl@getrow.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> mwe_select.tex
                  
! Emergency stop.
<*> mwe_select.tex
```

There is no `\par`, explicit or implict, to be found as far as I can tell.  I'm getting a feeling that there is something amiss in the bowels of datatool, but would appreciate another set of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

You almost did it! Only a few issues were left:

- `\DTselect`→`\addtodbfield`→`\DTLnewdbentry` is intended to add entries to the database denoted by `\DTselect`'s 3rd argument. But `\DTLnewdbentry` can only be applied if some row is available in the database due to `\DTLnewrow`.  In your code you do not call `\DTLnewrow` for adding rows to the database denoted by `\DTselect`'s 3rd argument. Applying `\DTLnewdbentry`  without `\DTLnewrow` causes the runaway-argument-error you encounter.
- With `\addtodbfield` you need `\dtlexpandnewvalue`.  The item to add is not denoted by `#3` but by `#4`.
- You define `\checkfordb` although there is `\DTLifdbexists`.

I suggest doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter

% Add fields #2 to a database #1
% #1->dbname, #2-><field name list>
\newcommand{\addcolstodb}[2]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\DTLaddcolumn{#1}{##1}}%
  \dolistloop{#2}}

% Add #4 to table #1 if #3 is in list of fields #2. Used in \DTselect below.
% #1->dbname, #2-><fieldname>, #3-><select fields>, #4->item
\newif\ifCreateNewRow
\newcommand{\addtodbfield}[4]{%
  \xifinlist{#2}{#3}%
  {%
    \ifCreateNewRow\CreateNewRowfalse\DTLnewrow{#1}\fi
    {\dtlexpandnewvalue\DTLnewdbentry{#1}{#2}{#4}}%
  }%
  {}%
}

\DTLnewdb{seqs}
\DTLaddcolumn{seqs}{id}
\DTLaddcolumn{seqs}{roman}
\DTLaddcolumn{seqs}{greek}
\DTLaddcolumn{seqs}{hebrew}

\define@key{addSeq}{roman}{\DTLnewdbentry{seqs}{roman}{#1}}
\define@key{addSeq}{greek}{\DTLnewdbentry{seqs}{greek}{#1}}
\define@key{addSeq}{hebrew}{\DTLnewdbentry{seqs}{hebrew}{#1}}

\newcommand{\addSeq}[2][]{%
  \DTLnewrow{seqs}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{seqs}{id}{#2}%
  \setkeys{addSeq}{#1}}

\newcommand{\makeTable}[2][]{%
    \DTLdisplaylongdb[{caption={Simple table #2},#1}]{#2}}

% Here is where the trouble was:
\newcommand*{\DTselect}[3]{%
  \DTLifdbexists{#1}{%
    \forcsvlist{\listadd\LDcols}{#2}%
    \DTLnewdb{#3}%
    \addcolstodb{#3}{\LDcols}%
    \DTLforeach*{#1}{}{%
      % \addtodbfield checks an if switch for deciding whether 
      % creating a new row is necessary - this way empty rows
      % within the #3-database can be avoided:
      \CreateNewRowtrue
      \DTLforeachkeyinrow{\LDvalue}{%
        \addtodbfield{#3}{\dtlkey}{\LDcols}{\LDvalue}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \errmessage{Table named #1 does not exist.}%
  }%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Set up a table
\addSeq[roman=A, greek=alpha, hebrew=aleph]{aaa}
\addSeq[roman=B, greek=beta, hebrew=beth]{bbb}
\addSeq[roman=D, greek=delta, hebrew=dalet]{ddd}
\addSeq[roman=G, greek=gamma, hebrew=gimel]{ggg}

% Print it
\makeTable{seqs}

\DTselect{seqs}{greek, hebrew}{foreign}
\makeTable{foreign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrich, many thanks for taking the time to look at this.  You have sharp eyes!  The only reason for \checkfordb is to issue a warning to the user if the db doesn't exist.  I moved the \DTnewrow into \DTselect and eliminated the boolean, but same thing.  You the man, Ulirch.

Comment: @DanielDoherty If you look at the change-history of my answer, then you will find that in the beginning I also had `\DTLnewrow` within `\DTselect`. ;-)  But `\DTLnewrow` within `\DTSelect` implies that for each row of the seqs-database a row will be created within the foreign-database **no matter if that row will be empty** because of the corresponding seqs-row not containing elements that are to be selected for the foreign-database. So I decided to use a boolean for the benefit of avoiding empty rows within the foreign-database.

Comment: Aha.  That makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification.